# Redirect back to the ASP.NET Mvc Client after Sign-out from IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I want to redirect back to my client after sign-out from local, then the IS4; My AspNetCore Mvc client works correctly and redirect back to the client after sign-out, but the **AspNet Mvc** (**not Core**) it doesn't.

here is my Startup.Configuration method:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {           
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Authority = "https://localhost:5000",

            UseTokenLifetime = false,              
            // RedeemCode = true,

            ClientId = "aspNet_client",               
            ClientSecret = "secret",                
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44343/sigin-oidc",              
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44343/signout-callback-oidc",               
            SaveTokens = true,            
            ResponseType = "code id_token",

            Scope = "openid profile offline_access",

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            },

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = onAuthenticationFailed,
                MessageReceived = onMessageReceived,

               // AuthorizationCodeReceived = onAuthorizationCodeReceived
            }
        });
    }
```

I used this method to sign-out:

```
public ActionResult SignOut()
{
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

I used this method too:

```
    public ActionResult SignOut()
    {
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                    new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44343"
                    },
                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
                    );

          //"Cookies", "OpenIdConnect"
    }
```

But not worked. So my question is:
How to automatic redirect back to my AspNetMvc Client after sign-out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an [error](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1000) reported long time ago on IdentityServer3. It got fixed [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/pull/2120) by setting `IdTokenHint` on logout. In this case as we use IdentityServer4, we can implement similar fix manually on ASP.NET MVC app. Here is changes need to make:

1. on IdentityServer project set `PostLogoutRedirectUris` for the client:

```
new Client
{
   ClientId = "aspNet_client",

   //All other settings ...

   PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:44343" },
},
```

2. On ASP.NET mvc application, set `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` - `PostLogoutRedirectUri` to the same value as step 1
3. Change `Notifications` - `SecurityTokenValidated` and `RedirectToIdentityProvider` to set `IdTokenHint` on logout

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // other settings...

                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:44343",
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        {
                            var id_token_claim = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "id_token");
                            if (id_token_claim != null)
                            {
                                n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = id_token_claim.Value;
                            }
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

4. If you want to redirect automatically set `AccountOptions` - `AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut` to `true` on IdentityServer, default value is `false`.

Implemented it myself [here](https://github.com/nahidf-adventures/IdentityServer4-adventures/tree/master/src/Net4MvcClient)